# Update ccmake on Ubuntu when building from source?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I previously installed `cmake` and `ccmake` version 2.8.7 on Ubuntu using `apt-get cmake` and `apt-get cmake-curses-gui`.  This is the most recent version available from apt-get.

I now need to update both to 3.1.1, and would like to do it from source.  I downloaded/configured/built/installed the source code for `cmake`.  `cmake` has updated, but `ccmake` has not:

```
$ cmake -- version
cmake version 3.1.1

$ ccmake --version
ccmake version 2.8.7
```

What do I need to do to update `ccmake`?

**Update:**

If I first `apt-get remove cmake` then `ccmake --version` gives me a no such file error.

Note: I've found a number of questions about cmake vs ccmake installation on Ubuntu [1], but I haven't found one that considers what to do when building from source.

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/121797/how-do-i-install-ccmake

Comment: Did you uninstall the apt versions?

Comment: No.  I just uninstalled it, and how cmake --version returns 3.1.1 and ccmake --version returns no such file or directory.

Comment: So `ccmake` probably didn't make it to the `$PATH`. Do you know where the binary ended up?

Comment: The install prefix was /usr/local, and I see cmake, cpack, and ctest in there, but not ccmake.

Comment: Are you sure the build succeeded?

Comment: Well, in so much as cmake ../src is able to build a simple example, yes--though I can't access ccmake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I eventually found thread [1], which solved my problem.  The steps I needed to take were:

1. Install libncurses5-dev
2. Reconfigure/compile/install cmake
3. Restart the shell (initially it was available, but the shell couldn't find it)

[1] http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-November/047654.html

Comment: I fixed it by running `cmake-gui` (the one previously installed without ccmake) in the sources directory of cmake itself (sounds strange but worked like a charm). Then, I looked for `BUILD_CursesDialog` (as suggested in this thread [1]) which wasn't checked. I checked it. Run configure & generate. Then `make -j4` & `sudo checkinstall`.