# ccmake does not link to the latest version of cmake on my ubuntu while building VTK (ccmake says cmake is version 3.5.1, whichi is not!)

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, vtk, cmake-gui

Actually, I think ccmake does not link to the latest version of cmake on my ubuntu.  While building VTKI've just updated my Cmake to version 3.15.0 still, the ccmake GUI does not recognize it. While I'm going to build the VTK package with the help from https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build The ccmake GUI says that :

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
 CMake 3.15 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1
```

Does anybody know what should I do?

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047829/ccmake-update-ubuntu-16-04-lts) on AskUbuntu? It seems it describes the very similar problem.

Comment: I actually did check that topic on AskUbuntu. The solution given there was to not use ccmake at all and do the ANT thing with another method. Problem is that I have to use ccmake in order to build the VTK package. Still the ccmake says the cmake version is 3.5.1.

Comment: "Problem is that I have to use ccmake in order to build the VTK package. " - `ccmake` is just a wrapper around `cmake`. You may set configuration variables via `-D` option for `cmake`. Or you may write *pre-load* CMake script, which assigns multiple variables. Path to that script you may pass via `-C` option for `cmake`. See documentation about `cmake` executable here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake.1.html

Comment: BTW, the [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111300/3440745) describes how to properly build CMake with GUI.